# Java creating dynamic multidimensional array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Who can help me with creating dynamic multidimensional array using recursion.
I need to create a function with the depth of the array and the number of children

The depth of the array  may be of different sizes

```
class Item {
    public int id;
    public Map<Integer, Item>[] children;
}

Map<Integer, Item> items = new HashMap<>();

function void build(int depth, int countChildren) {
    ...
}

function Item createItem() {
    Item item = new Item();
    item.id = Math.Random(0,10000);

    return item;
}
```

Array looks like this

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQiR6.png)

```php
[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 10,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'id' => 20,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 10,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'id' => 20,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

Comment: Are you...are you trying to do something with a JSON response, perhaps?  (That looks like neither JSON nor Java arrays - looks more like PHP.)

Comment: It also looks a bit like an XML tree.  XML deals with that by having each node able to have any number of child nodes.

Comment: It just example. I try build tree array dynamically

Comment: I try create array like in image